# Get data from firebase with future task

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I've got problem with getting data from firebase, because operation is asynchronous. In javascript it wasn't problem, because there is promises, but in java I don't know how to do this with future task and java isn't my power. I need to make the operation with future task in while loop and to wait until the result is ready for use. Can you help me?